# How to use Cache in ASP.NET MVC web application?

Tags: caching, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to use cache in this way for the application I have.

in first request data come from database and passing them to view from controller and storing them in cache.

in next request I want to get the data from cache and putted them in page and asynchronously get the data from database again and check if something new come then update the cache so.

because in last request data come from cache it's goes faster and update the cache for future request.

How I can implement this thing in my application  [MVC 3]?